# Join tables having the same primary key

Tags: sql, join, view

How do I join three tables having the same primary key and make one view ? Any leads would be appreciated.

I have 3 tables `sttm_customer`, `sttm_customer_c` and `sttm_customer_custom`,
 that have customer_no in common with all.

I need to make one view `STVW_CUSTOMER_TEMP` merging all of them.

Comment: Also, there are some more columns in common of all the three tables.

Comment: Why do you have 3 almost similar tables? Seems like poor db design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can use UNION:

```
SELECT customer_no (and any other matching columns)
FROM sttm_customer
UNION 
SELECT customer_no (and any other matching columns)
FROM sttm_customer_c 
UNION customer_no (and any other matching columns)
FROM sttm_customer_custom
```